# Use of dissoc's unary version?

Tags: clojure, arity

While using `dissoc`, I noticed it has a unary version which didn't seem to do anything. I checked the source, and it turns out it's just the identity function:

```
(defn dissoc
  ([map] map)
  ([map key]
   (. clojure.lang.RT (dissoc map key)))
  ([map key & ks]
   (let [ret (dissoc map key)]
     (if ks
       (recur ret (first ks) (next ks))
       ret))))
```

then I noticed that `disj` has a unary version as well with the same definition.

What is the purpose of the unary versions? The only potential use I can see is maybe when they're used with `apply`, but I don't see how this would be useful. And why don't their `conj` and `assoc` counterparts have similar unary versions?

Comment: Consider `(apply dissoc some-map items-to-remove)`. Do you *really* want it to be an error when `items-to-remove` is empty, and thus to force anyone using that idiom to wrap it in a conditional?

Comment: It's exactly the same as how `+` also has 0- and 1-argument versions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a good point. I think it didn't click since I've never used `apply` on any of the functions before. I'll accept that if you write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider `(apply dissoc some-map items-to-remove)`.

If the unary form didn't exist, `items-to-remove` being empty would be an error, and thus one would need to always check its length before making this call.

Comment: It follows that `conj` and `assoc` ought to be unary identities too. Does a JIRA ticket beckon?

Comment: @Thumbnail I would say that any usage of `apply` with `conj` should be replaced with [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into). For using `apply` with `assoc`, it doesn't seem to be so straightforward; you could use `#(into %1 (map vec (partition-all 2 %2)))`, but that's relatively long.

Comment: @Thumbnail `conj` has had a unary overload since 1.7.0. It's obscured in `(doc conj)`, as is indeed the nullary overload that was introduced at the same time. Ticket to fix that by updating `:arglists` (with patch): https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2169

Comment: @SamEstep `into` may be preferable, Sam. But that's a different question. What's at stake is consistency and uniformity. If `conj` (or `assoc`) accepts several (pairs of) arguments after the first, it ought to accept none: `conj` does, `assoc` doesn't. `list*` - an extension of `cons`, accepts just one argument.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk Thank you. I'll be less credulous in future.

Comment: @Thumbnail No argument there; I absolutely agree on the consistency point, and as I mentioned in my previous comment, there isn't a particularly good alternative for `assoc`anyway.